# How find this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{[(2n)!]^2}$

Tags: analysis

Find the sum
$$I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{[(2n)!]^2}$$

I think we can note
$$\dfrac{n}{((2n)!)^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{2n}{((2n)!)^2)}=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(2n)!\cdot(2n-1)!}$$

Comment: That is correct

Comment: an explicit formual contains the Bessel function

Answer (score 1):

The series expansion of the [Bessel function of first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind_:_J.CE.B1), $J_\nu(x)$, and the [modified Bessel function of first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), $I_\nu(x)=i^{-\nu}J_\nu(ix)$, are given by
$$J_\nu(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \, \Gamma(m+\nu+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\nu}\\
I_\nu(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m! \, \Gamma(m+\nu+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\nu}$$
Chosing, $\nu=1$ we find that
$$J_1(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \, (m+1)!} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+1}\\
I_1(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m! \, (m+1)!} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+1}$$
Doing $I_1(x)-J_1(x)$, only the coefficients with $m$ odd will survive and we will have
\begin{align}I_1(x)-J_1(x)&=\sum_{m\,\text{odd}} \frac{2}{m! \, (m+1)!} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{(2n)! \, (2n-1)!} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{4n-1}\end{align}
Using your expression, we find that
$$I=\frac{1}{4}(I_1(2)-J_1(2))$$